# Parse serialized JSON

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, mobile, serialization

I'm using Wordpress JSON API plugin to generate JSON for use in a mobile app.

The data is from custom fields in custom post types in Wordpress (created via a plugin called WCK)

An extract from the JSON of the wordpress custom fields looks like this

```
custom_fields: {
sitedetails: [
"a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:14:"site-reference";s:4:"A428";s:9:"site-name";s:11:"Main street";s:16:"site-description";s:19:"A great development";s:10:"site-image";s:2:"70";s:24:"site-data-version-number";s:3:"1.0";}}"
],
plotdetails: [
"a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:14:"plot-reference";s:5:"A4282";s:12:"plot-address";s:42:"9 Highers Way Threwsbury Thropshire XY11AA";s:10:"plot-image";s:2:"70";s:12:"map-latitude";s:9:"22.111122";s:13:"map-longitude";s:9:"-9.334455";s:13:"plot-postcode";s:7:"XY11AA";s:24:"plot-data-version-number";s:3:"1.0";}}"
],
ownersdetails: [
"a:0:{}"
],
housingassociation: [
"a:0:{}"
],
movingin: [
"a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:16:"moving-in-advice";s:91:"Make sure you know where the various stop-valves and main electrical switches are located. ";}}"
],
repairstoyourhome: [
"a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:14:"repairs-advice";s:9:"Take care";s:12:"phone-number";s:13:"0123 45 67 89";s:7:"website";s:21:"http://www.google.com";s:5:"email";s:16:"google@gmail.com";s:24:"repairs-additional-notes";s:11:"Please call";}}"
],
certificates: [
"a:5:{i:0;a:3:{s:16:"certificate-name";s:34:"NICEIC Electrical Test Certificate";s:17:"certificate-notes";s:24:"Refer to your paper copy";s:20:"certificate-document";s:0:"";}i:1;a:3:{s:16:"certificate-name";s:20:"Gas Safe Certificate";s:17:"certificate-notes";s:24:"Refer to your paper copy";s:20:"certificate-document";s:0:"";}i:2;a:3:{s:16:"certificate-name";s:23:"Smoke Alarm Certificate";s:17:"certificate-notes";s:19:"Refer to paper copy";s:20:"certificate-document";s:0:"";}i:3;a:3:{s:16:"certificate-name";s:30:"Energy Performance Certificate";s:17:"certificate-notes";s:19:"Refer to paper copy";s:20:"certificate-document";s:0:"";}i:4;a:3:{s:16:"certificate-name";s:29:"Sustainable Homes Certificate";s:17:"certificate-notes";s:19:"Refer to paper copy";s:20:"certificate-document";s:0:"";}}"
],
```

The majority of the JSON data is easily accessed using "$.each". But the custom_fields holds data which appears to be serialized in arrays (there are "Repeater fields" which are prefixed with a:n where a indicates array and n is the number of occurrences of that array (I think).

So, I'm looking for an easy way of de-serializing the data so I can get access to each array and each element of the array.

Has anyone done this and have an example?

I can access the specific custom field using (for example)

```
data.post.custom_fields.sitedetails
data.post.custom_fields.plotdetails
```

etc

But can't find a simple jquery way of unpacking the serialized data.

The code uses Ajax to download the JSON within a jquery mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

var

```
obj = JSON.parse( yourJsonVariable );
```

but your JSON is on a complete malformation...

it ends with a comma...
and objects like certificates are missing escape characters:

```
certificates: [
"a:5:{i:0;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:34:\"NICEIC Electrical Test Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:24:\"Refer to your paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:1;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:20:\"Gas Safe Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:24:\"Refer to your paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:2;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:23:\"Smoke Alarm Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:19:\"Refer to paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:3;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:30:\"Energy Performance Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:19:\"Refer to paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:4;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:29:\"Sustainable Homes Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:19:\"Refer to paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}}"
],
```

after this you shoud parse it an access like you want:

```
obj = JSON.parse( youJsonVariable );
obj.custom_fields.certificates[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to make the JSON readable. It actually looks like this:-

Answer (score 0):

Actual JSON as received in jquery:-

```
"custom_fields":{"sitedetails":["a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:14:\"site-reference\";s:4:\"A428\";s:9:\"site-name\";s:11:\"Main street\";s:16:\"site-description\";s:19:\"A great development\";s:10:\"site-image\";s:2:\"70\";s:24:\"site-data-version-number\";s:3:\"1.0\";}}"],"plotdetails":["a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:14:\"plot-reference\";s:5:\"A4282\";s:12:\"plot-address\";s:42:\"9 Highers Way\nThrewsbury\nThropshire\nXY11AA\";s:10:\"plot-image\";s:2:\"70\";s:12:\"map-latitude\";s:9:\"22.112233\";s:13:\"map-longitude\";s:9:\"-9.121212\";s:13:\"plot-postcode\";s:7:\"XY1 1AA\";s:24:\"plot-data-version-number\";s:3:\"1.0\";}}"],"ownersdetails":["a:0:{}"],"housingassociation":["a:0:{}"],"movingin":["a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:16:\"moving-in-advice\";s:91:\"Make sure you know where the various stop-valves and main electrical switches are located.\n\";}}"],"repairstoyourhome":["a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:14:\"repairs-advice\";s:9:\"Take care\";s:12:\"phone-number\";s:13:\"0123 45 67 89\";s:7:\"website\";s:21:\"http:\/\/www.google.com\";s:5:\"email\";s:16:\"google@gmail.com\";s:24:\"repairs-additional-notes\";s:11:\"Please call\";}}"],"certificates":["a:5:{i:0;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:34:\"NICEIC Electrical Test Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:24:\"Refer to your paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:1;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:20:\"Gas Safe Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:24:\"Refer to your paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:2;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:23:\"Smoke Alarm Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:19:\"Refer to paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:3;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:30:\"Energy Performance Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:19:\"Refer to paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}i:4;a:3:{s:16:\"certificate-name\";s:29:\"Sustainable Homes Certificate\";s:17:\"certificate-notes\";s:19:\"Refer to paper copy\";s:20:\"certificate-document\";s:0:\"\";}}"],
```